# If return statement is executed in run function of a thread does the thread stop in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I was confused that a thread is automatically stops after executing the return statement or it still remains alive.
This is code like:

```
public void run{
 //code goes here
 return;//does the thread stops here;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't actually make any difference. Since the thread can't do anything at that point, and you can't make it do anything, how could you tell if it was still alive or not? Java doesn't require the implementation to do things one way or another way if there's no way you could tell the difference anyway.

Comment: @David Schwartz: He might be concerned whether the thread's resources are released or not.

Comment: @Tudor: True, in which case the answer is: "They are eligible to be reclaimed. So you're not wasting resources. The implementation will only fail to reclaim them if it thinks that is best." (For example, it may keep a few threads around to be reused if it wants to.) Or, alternatively, "As far as you are concerned, yes."

Comment: Yes i am concerned about the resources are released or not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, a Java thread stops when its `run` method terminates.

Now, this information is, let's say, "common knowledge", because the purpose of the `Thread` class is to wrap a portion of code and terminate when the code finishes executing.

There is no explicit way to assert this behavior by studying the [source code of java.lang.Thread](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Thread.java.html) because at some point a native method called `start0` is executed.

Answer (score 0):

do have a thread keep on running you have to do something like the following:

```
boolean stop;

public void run() {
    while(!stop) {

    }
}
```